# Error connecting to localstack container on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline, localstack

I'm trying to create a an s3 bucket on jenkins using localstack, like so

```
      stage('Start Localstack') {
        steps {
            script {
                // create a custom network
                sh 'docker network create new-network'
                sh 'docker run --network new-network --name localstack -d -p 4566:4566 -e SERVICES=s3 localstack/localstack'
                sh 'sleep 20'
                
                // *** new steps ***
                sh 'docker ps'
                sh 'curl 0.0.0.0:4566/_localstack/health'
                // *** / ***

                // create an s3 bucket in localstack
                withEnv(['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=test', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=test-secret']) {
                    sh 'aws s3 mb s3://pricing.s3.engine --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the pipeline fails with

```
+ aws s3 mb s3://pricing.s3.engine --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566
make_bucket failed: s3://pricing.s3.engine Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/pricing.s3.engine"
```

EDIT:
I added a couple of intermediate steps before creating the container

```
sh 'docker ps'
sh 'curl 0.0.0.0:4566/_localstack/health'
```

`docker ps` shows the container is created

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS 
852bf19dc492   localstack/localstack             "docker-entrypoint.sh"   33 seconds ago   Up 32 seconds (healthy)   4510-4559/tcp, 5678/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4566->4566/tcp
```

But the curl fails with

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 4566: Connection refused
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues using LocalStack on Jenkins that seems related to this.  I've used docker compose to add the LocalStack container to the network  the rest of my application's containers are running in, but I think it's possible the problem is the same.  I found I needed to use a different hostname to reach LocalStack within the network provided by docker compose.

Try changing the `--endpoint-url` you specify when you create the bucket to "http://localstack:4566".  I think you need to use the network name you specified at the start.